# Rails - A better way to parse the time with a timezone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, timezone

Time.parse returns a Time object that does not have a timezone.  I would like to keep the timezone information.  Is there a better way to do this then the following code?

```
def parse_with_timezone( string_input)
  /(.*)([+-]\d\d):?(\d\d)$/.match( string_input) do |match|
    tz = ActiveSupport::TimeZone[match[2].to_i.hours + match[3].to_i.minutes]
    tz.parse( match[1])
  end
end
```

The input is a string like this "2012-12-25T00:00:00+09:00".  This function outputs a TimeWithZone object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Were you looking for a specific timezone of the current local one?

```
# Current zone
1.9.3p194> Time.zone.parse('2012-12-25T00:00:00+09:00')
=> Mon, 24 Dec 2012 15:00:00 UTC +00:00
```

Console was set at UTC for above but will work for whatever you have configured

```
# Specific timezone 
1.9.3p194> Time.find_zone('Wellington').parse('2012-12-25T00:00:00+09:00')
=> Tue, 25 Dec 2012 04:00:00 NZDT +13:00
```

I notice you're trying to pass +9 so as an example

```
1.9.3p194> Time.zone = 'Tokyo'
=> "Tokyo" 
1.9.3p194> Time.zone.parse('2012-12-25T00:00:00+09:00')
=> Tue, 25 Dec 2012 00:00:00 JST +09:00
```

Gives you the right result.

Comment: I don't know what the timezone is in advance.  That's why I'm parsing it.

Comment: There's no single timezone at any given timezone offset. The best you could hope for would be an array of available timezones. This really would have no value to you as each timezone could be in different Daylight Savings areas. Timezones are not trivial offsets so I'm not sure that I understand what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

What about the Rails Timezone API: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use [Chronic](http://chronic.rubyforge.org/) for all my date/time parsing needs.

Comment: Chronic won't help me.  It states at the bottom of that link, "Time zones other than the local one are not currently supported."